# Enable debug log for standalone BI Publisher 10g deployed on weblogic

Tags: debugging, logging, weblogic, business-intelligence, bi-publisher

How can I enable debug log for standalone BI Publisher 10g deployed on weblogic?

I have tried creating xdodebug.cfg file with necessary statements, and placed it under JDK/jre/lib folder. I have set the log level to debug in bi publisher. Yet I donot see xdo.log file.

This procedure works on OAS but not with weblogic. Anyone knows how to make bip 10g deployed on weblogic create log files.

Thanks.

Comment: did you work out an answer for this question ?